# Drag nested li doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery-ui for sort and drag https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/.. But it doesn't append in li..
The code is like

```js
$("#example3 ul").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: '#example3 ul'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="example3">
    <ul>
        <li >Item 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 2</li>
                <li>Item 1 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li >Item 2<ul></ul></li>
        <li >Item 3<ul></ul></li>
        <li >Item 4<ul></ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I drag item 3 to under item 2 then it doesn't work..How can I solve this?? and also I have to detect that which li goes under which li.. please Help..

Comment: Mh? You say that, it does not work, "if I drag item 3 to under item 2", but 3 is alyways under 2.

Comment: @TobiasK. item 3 under item 2 as a child

Comment: Ah okay, solution is given below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, that the empty 'ul'-Tags does not have any space and are hidden (size is equals zero). Just add a small padding to each element, then you can drag your element there. Here, have a look:

```js
$("#example3 ul").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    connectWith: '#example3 ul'
});
```

```css
#example3 ul{
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="example3">
    <ul>
        <li >Item 1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1 1</li>
                <li>Item 1 2</li>
                <li>Item 1 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li >Item 2<ul></ul></li>
        <li >Item 3<ul></ul></li>
        <li >Item 4<ul></ul></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought same so but didn't think about padding.. cheers.. thankss :)

Comment: can u tell me how to detect which li goes under which li??

Comment: That is done by the lib's :) I do not detect anything.

Comment: No..I meant that item 3 goes under item 2..now I have to detect that which index goes under which index..